# Xcode autocompletion issues

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autocomplete

Ever since `Xcode 6` I've been having issues with autocompletion. Specifically, when I'm programming in `Swift` I fail to get autocomplete suggestions for most things outside of the variables or functions declared within the current file.

When I try to `Esc` my way to a suggestion, I get this weird type to the left of the suggestion.

[image]

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
```

`managedContext` in this case is a local constant. Is there a fix for this?

My Xcode version is

[image]

Comment: Show us the `managedContext` declaration.

Comment: @rintaro I've updated my question with it, but I doubt there's anything wrong with it.